# Is there a topology on natural numbers being not first countable?

Tags: general-topology, natural-numbers, first-countable

A topology on a countable set may be uncountable, such as discrete topology on natural numbers. Although that topology has uncountably many set, it is first countable, indeed, second countable. I wonder that is there a topology on natural numbers being not first countable?

Comment: Note that a countable space is first countable if and only if it is second countable.

Comment: My answer is not [Are countable topological spaces second-countable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3272545/are-countable-topological-spaces-second-countable). Unfortinately, the theorem you write "a countable space is first countable if and only if it is second countable" doesn't answer for the question.

Comment: The answer says that there is a non second-countable topology on $\mathbb{N}$. And thus it is also non first-countable based on the theorem. Everything you need is there.

Comment: Thank you for your attention.